# Open WebSocket connection to SalesForce live chat

Tags: java, websocket, salesforce

Is there possibility to open websocket connection to salesforce live chat instead of rest api?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. As documentation, you should use long polling.

[Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_http_long_polling_loop.htm)